# How can I add custom js tags on magento after events?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Add to Cart

You can track the following action/event using:

```
RmClient.track("Added to Cart",{
"categories": ["For Men"],
"sku": "<SKU>",
"title": "Cento for male",
"price": 75
});
RmClient.send();
```

Checkout

You can track the following action/event using:

```
RmClient.track("Checkout",{
"products": ["<SKU_1>", "<SKU_2>"],
"total_cost": 1520,
"Subtotal": 1520
});
RmClient.send();
```

Purchased

You can track the following action/event using:
Note: You can also share revenue or value (both Number values) as part of event to take advantage of our revenue reports.

```
 RmClient.track("Product Purchased",{
    "categories": ["For Men"],
    "sku": "<SKU>",
    "title": "Cento for male",
    "revenue": 75
});
RmClient.send();
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not asking a question. Blog posts and how-to posts belong on blogs, not here.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to create the event observer for all you calls at different points. You can use the existing module or create a new module for that purpose. Then you can follow the below tutorial to get your calls right :
http://alanstorm.com/magento_javascript_events/

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you anoop!       Can you provide me a code structure for after 'add to cart' getting product details? my email sanalnly at gmail dot com